# local time parser doesnt work [java]

Tags: java

Beneath the question I have put my code.For some reason it can't parse 6:00 and 17:30 to localtime and then put it as boolean in the ifstatetement, if it is before 6:00 put the values in the nachtMap, if it is after 17:30 , put it as well in the NachtMap, otherwise in Daymap (its basically all in the for loop).
Any one who knows whats wron with my code?

```
// for each license plate
            for (int i = 1, n = licenseplateList.size(); i < n; i++) {

                //first look at whether it is considered as day or night time


                try {

                    String time1Str = begintimeList.get(i);
                String time2Str = endingtimeList.get(i);

                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
                LocalTime time1 = LocalTime.parse(time1Str, formatter);
                LocalTime time2 = LocalTime.parse(time2Str, formatter);

                // add date value: start with today
                LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
                // lower value will be assigned to today
                LocalDateTime dateTime1 = LocalDateTime.of(today, time1);
                // upper value will be assigned same day if it is after lower value
                // otherwise (we crossed date boundary) assign it to tomorrow
                LocalDateTime dateTime2 =   time2.isAfter(time1) ?
                        LocalDateTime.of(today, time2) : LocalDateTime.of(today.plusDays(1), time2);

                Duration duration = Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2);
                Duration halfDuration = duration.dividedBy(2);
                LocalTime result = LocalTime.from(halfDuration.addTo(time1));

                System.out.println(result.format(formatter));

                LocalTime calc = LocalTime.parse("6:00");
                LocalTime calc2 = LocalTime.parse("17:30");
                boolean before = result.format(formatter).before(calc);
                boolean after = result.format(formatter).after(calc2);

                if (before == true) {
                    nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), kmperlineList.get(i)); 

                }
                else {
                    if(after == true) {

                        nachtMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), kmperlineList.get(i));
                    }
                    else {
                        dagMap.put(licenseplateList.get(i), kmperlineList.get(i));
                    }
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

Comment: Parsing `17:30` works just fine. You can't parse `6:00`, use `06:00` instead.

Comment: but theres more wrong with my code as it cant find the symbol (before), the imports are right, pretty sure

Comment: If you post a well laid-out [mcve] and describe one problem you need help with, you are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: done bro [6 more]

Comment: Catching `Exception` with an empty catch block is asking for trouble. "If anything goes wrong, just carry on like everything's fine and don't tell me."

Comment: What you have posted is not minimal, complete, or well laid-out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use `H:mm` instead of `HH:mm`, it can parse both `06:00` and `6:00`

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm");
    Assert.assertEquals(
        LocalTime.parse("6:00", formatter),
        LocalTime.parse("06:00", formatter)
    );
}
```

Comment: Gonna try that bro. But I'm mostly concerned about this line boolean before = result.format(formatter).before(calc); is this a legal thing to do, should this work properly if the formats right